# Squid: how to block a website, but allow access to certain folders

Tags: squid

I want to block `gstatic.com` website in Squid, but allow access to `gstatic.com/recaptcha/*`. When I write this in the white list:

```
gstatic\.com/recaptcha/*
```

it doesn't work. When I write the domain name:

```
gstatic\.com
```

It allows access to the entire website.

squid.conf:

```
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
acl bad_domain dstdom_regex "/etc/squid/block.acl"
acl good_domain dstdom_regex "/etc/squid/white.acl"

http_access deny bad_domain
http_access allow good_domain
http_access deny all
```

Answer (score 1):

Three obvious things are wrong here.

1. allow rules should come before deny.
2. `dstdom_regex` only matches the hostname portion of the URL, everything else is ignored - you probably want a `url_regex` or `urlpath_regex` instead.
3. `dstdom_regex "/etc/squid/white.acl"` does not do what you think it does.  It does not load a file containing a bunch of acls.  If you want to do that, then you need to create a file containing one acl definition per line and `include` it in your squid.conf - e.g. `include /etc/squid/white.acl`
   The same applies for `dstdom_regex "/etc/squid/block.acl"`